# Gamecenter Turnbased Timelimit for turns

Tags: ios, time, push-notification, game-center, multiplayer

I'm working on a iphone & ipad, gamecenter turnbased game.

I would like to build-in a time limit for each turn. Every player should only have 48 hours to complete their turn. When the player is running out of time, he/she should get a notification to hurry up. 
If a player doesn't take the turn within the time limit, he's out of the game (and gets another notification).
The popular game Wordfeud works like this but they have there own server (not via Apple's gameCenter).

As far as I know, NSNotificationCenter has only one notification for GameCenter and that is Authentication did change.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement these notifications in my game ?

Answer (score 0):

no dice. you can't kill the games without the app running. 
However, you can give the user the impression of it, if you want to do so you can use local notifications (see `UILocalNotification` and `-[UIApplication scheduleLocalNotification:]` for a way to start)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6.0 and later you can end turns with the following method

```
- (void)endTurnWithNextParticipants:(NSArray *)nextParticipants turnTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout matchData:(NSData *)matchData completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler
```

You can define you timeout interval. If the player does not take or plays in that interval then the next player takes the turn.